# Secure implementation of public key cryptography

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature, diffie-hellman, implementation

Reading online I've found out that for example the RSA implementation that you usually find on textook is not secure.
Where I can find some secure implementation of algorithm such as RSA, ECDH, ECDSA?

(written in C or C++ or python)

Comment: Did you check OpenSSL, BearSSL?

Comment: @kelalaka yes, I've read it on github, but it's not an easy lecture, I was hoping for something more simple.

Comment: What's taught in textbooks are different what's specified in industry standards like PKCS#1, SEC#1, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Libsodium is written/implementable in C++, C and Python. It implements lots of crypto systems, such as public key cryptography. Here is the intro in the docs: https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/

Comment: I didn't find the algorithm that I'm looking for. Probably they implements some other crypto

Comment: Here is the PDF for the Python bindings (PyNaCl), and they have lots of stuff about public key crypto ie for elliptic curves etc...: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://readthedocs.org/projects/pynacl/downloads/pdf/latest/&ved=2ahUKEwjy3auh3vvmAhUQGsAKHclBCO0QFjAHegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3AEI5-PgWM3dLs2fWqNAQX

Answer (score 1):

I think Crypto++ will help you. This is a cryptography library implemented in C++. Its homepage: [Crypto++ Library](https://www.cryptopp.com/).